# Flutter : Space between SlidableAction

Tags: flutter, dart

Is it possible to have a space between SlidableAction and its child on `flutter_slidable: ^3.0.1` ?
Like a margin rigth for the green part.

SlidableAction and its child

[image]

Thanks

This the code

```
child: Slidable(
    startActionPane: ActionPane(
        motion: const BehindMotion(),
        extentRatio: 0.20,
        children: [
          SlidableAction(
            onPressed: (context) {},
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
            backgroundColor: Colors.green,
            foregroundColor: Colors.white,
            label: 'Fini',
            icon: Icons.done,
          ),
        ]),
    child: Container(...)
```

I didn't see any option for that, I've try so many things.
I'm a beginner in Flutter.

Comment: provide code so we can know more about your problem

Comment: wrap ActionPane's each child with padding.

Answer (score 0):

Using `SlidableAction` does not allow you to configure any margins between actions (`ActionPane` children). This widget supposed to be the direct child of `ActionPane`.

You should try to do that via providing `CustomSlidableAction` where you will have a `Padding` or `Container` widget to make margins possible.

Also this [comment and discussion](https://github.com/letsar/flutter_slidable/issues/228#issuecomment-884690374) should be an additional help

Comment: I've try your solution but my `SlidableAction` disappears. 
I wrap it whit a container widget with a margin

Comment: You should not use `SlidableAction` if you want to make margins around it. It is not its purpose. Use `CustomSlidableAction` instead, inside `builder` method you can create a container with margins

Comment: my bad... still not working for me, maybe you have a code exemple ? 
this is what i've try: 
`Builder`
    `Container`
    `margin`
        `CustomSlidableAction `